# Something strange in mysql query because of Group By Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table which recording exam results for the users:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `xid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade` double NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `trues` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `falses` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `empties` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `xid` (`xid`),
  KEY `lid` (`lid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And I have this records in the table:

```
|id|uid|xid|lid|grade|duration|trues|falses|empties|    
+--+---+---+---+-----+--------+-----+------+-------+ 
|45| 20|  1|  1|   80|00:01:12|    8|     2|      0|
|46| 20|  1|  2|   40|00:02:31|    4|     6|      0|
|47| 20|  3|  1|  100|00:01:10|    1|     0|      0|
|48| 20|  4|  1|   83|00:00:51|    5|     1|      0|
|49| 20|  2|  1|    0|00:00:02|    0|     1|      0|
|53| 20|  4|  2|   50|00:00:04|    1|     1|      0|
|54| 20|  1|  2|   50|00:00:41|    5|     5|      0|
```

`lid` indicates the difficulty level of exam which is represented by `xid`. I want to show the highest grades for each unique exams with unique levels. For example there are 7 rows. and id[46] and id[54] are for the same exams and levels. So I must list the higher grade value among these two rows.

I have made a query:

```
SELECT 
      failed.fgrade, 
      succeeded.sgrade, 
      ts.xid, 
      ts.lid, 
      ts.trues, 
      ts.falses, 
      ts.empties,  
      MAX(`grade`) AS grade, 
      ts.duration, 
      x.exam 
FROM 
      ts
JOIN 
      x ON ts.xid = x.id
JOIN 
      (SELECT 
             COUNT(DISTINCT(xid))  AS sgrade 
       FROM ts 
       WHERE uid = 20 AND grade >= 70) AS succeeded

JOIN 
      (SELECT 
             COUNT(DISTINCT(xid)) AS fgrade 
       FROM ts 
       WHERE uid = 20 AND grade < 70 ) AS failed

WHERE 
       ts.uid = 20

GROUP BY 
      xid, 
      lid
ORDER BY 
      ts.id
```

When I run the query I get strange result:

```
Exam Name  Level    Duration     True   False   Empty    Total Grade  fgrade sgrade
Functions      1    00:00:02        0       1       0        1     0       3      3 
Numbers        2    00:02:31        4       6       0       10    50       3      3 (!) 
Equations      2    00:00:04        1       1       0        2    50       3      3 
Numbers        1    00:01:12        8       2       0       10    80       3      3 
Equations      1    00:00:51        5       1       0        6    83       3      3
Functions      1    00:01:10        1       0       0        1   100       3      3
```

If you look at the (!) row in the result table there is something weird. 4 correct answers and 6 false answers make 40 points. But it shows the other row's grade value while showing own true and false answer counts.

I am basically wishing to show the all different exams for each difficulty levels for a given userid (`uid`). Now as I am writing this question, I am starting to think that it may be due to the `GROUP BY` statement. But it has taken a while to write the question. I cannot delete this.

Comment: Where's the `ON` for your last 2 joins?  Really, why are those joins even there?

Answer (score 1):

Consider two rows below:

```
|46| 20|  1|  2|   40|00:02:31|    4|     6|      0|
|54| 20|  1|  2|   50|00:00:41|    5|     5|      0|
```

when group by xid, lid only one row are selected (first row)

```
|46| 20|  1|  2|   40|00:02:31|    4|     6|      0|
```

But for max(grade), it is an aggregate function, it mean that it will look up for all result row for get max value --> max(grade) return 50. 
-- > If you put grade and also max(grade) in your select, you will receive both 40 and 50.

In your case, I think you should join two ts table for get higher value for grade like this:

```
select ts1.* from ts ts1 left join ts laster on ts1.xid = laster.xid and ts1.lid = laster.lid
and ts1.uid = laster.uid and ts1.grade < laster.grade where isnull(laster.grade)
```

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake, ts2 mean laster.